# Packet Capturing/Latency time in java

Tags: java

I am looking for HTTPS packet capturing code in java . But i am getting procedure for HTTP. As per our requirement we need HTTPS packet capturing code. Can anybody give me the link for that or would tell me where can I find it?.

Comment: What exactly would you do with a pile of encrypted streams?

Comment: actuallay i want to calculate time difference between 2 packets received for latency time

Answer (score 2):

[jNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com/) might be what you're looking for: it is a java wrapper around the native libpcap library that sarnold mentions. From the [basic capture example](http://jnetpcap.com/examples/classic) provided, it seems that it would be fairly straightforward to write a `PcapPacketHandler` to time the arrival of packets on an HTTPS stream.

It will, however, add native dependencies to your project, which will complicate packaging up your software.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest starting with [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html) (or its sibling, [winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) on Windows), and then interpreting the saved captures; the libpcap team has done a fantastic job making a very reliable and fast mechanism to interface with the kernel's raw sockets support to run as efficiently as possible. (The Linux kernel provides a [BPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Packet_Filter)-like interface for specifying *which* packets to offload to userspace; see `Documentation/networking/filter.txt` for Linux details.)

Comment: As it sounds like you want to do this from within Java, you may want to take a look at jNetPCap, which looks like a fairly comprehensive wrapper around libpcap: http://jnetpcap.com/

Comment: @iainmcgin, you should submit that as an answer :) it looks like a better answer than mine.

Comment: AS Packets are on TCP layer and i am making connection through Http Post how should i implement this in my code so that , i can know at what time each  packet is coming at my end